# Python removing tuples from list that satisfy given conditions

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples and i want to remove tuples so that there is only one tuple in the list that has a given length and sum.

That's a bad explanation so for example:

```
[(0,1,2), (0,2,1), (0,0,1)]
```

remove (0,1,2) or (0,2,1)

I want to be able to iterate though the list and remove any tuples that satisfy the following conditions:

```
len(tuple1) == len(tuple2) and sum(tuple1) == sum(tuple2)
```

but keep either tuple1 or tuple2 in the list.

I tried:

```
for t1 in list:
    for t2 in list:
           if len(t1) == len(t2) and sum(t1) == sum(t2):
               list.remove(t1)
```

but im pretty sure this removes all tuples and the console crashed.

Comment: It is also very unsafe to *iterate* and *modify* a collection at the same time, so this is not the way to go.

Comment: what if tuple [a,b,c,d,e,a'] - should only a or a' stay in or do you only test neighboring ones?

Answer (score 3):

In essence this is a "uniqness filter", but where we specify a function `f`, and only if that `f(x)` occurs a second time, we filter that element out.

We can implement such uniqness filter, given `f(x)` produces *hashable* values, with:

```
def uniq(iterable, key=lambda x: x):
    seen = set()
    for item in iterable:
        u = key(item)
        if u not in seen:
            yield item
            seen.add(u)
```

Then we can use this filter as:

```
result = list(uniq(data, lambda x: (len(x), sum(x))))
```

for example:

```
>>> list(uniq(data, lambda x: (len(x), sum(x))))
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 1)]
```

Here we will always retain the first occurrence of the "duplicates".

Answer (score 2):

Let me offer a slightly different solution. Note that this is not something I'd use for a one-off script, but for a real project. Because your `[(0, 0, 1)]` actually represents something logical/physical.

`set(..)` removes duplicates. How about we use that? The only thing to keep it mind is that the hash value and equality of the elements need to be modified.

```
class Converted(object):
    def __init__(self, tup):
        self.tup = tup
        self.transformed = len(tup), sum(tup)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.transformed == other.transformed

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.transformed)

inp = [(0,1,2), (0,2,1), (0,0,1)]
out = [x.tup for x in set(map(Converted, inp))]
print(out)
# [(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to just make a new list that meets your conditions.

```
old_list = [(0,1,2), (0,2,1), (0,0,1)]
new_list = []
for old_t in old_list:
    for new_t in new_list:
        if len(old_t) == len(new_t) and sum(old_t) == sum(new_t):
            break
    else:
        new_list.append(old_t)

# new_list == [(0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 1)]
```

Comment: Python `for` has `else` clause.

Comment: @NizamMohamed I always forget about that, fixed in edit, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group elements by `sum` and `len` and fetch 1 element from each group to create a new list:

```
from itertools import groupby

def _key(t):
    return (len(t), sum(t))

data = [(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1), (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (3, 0, 0, 0)]
result = []
for k, g in groupby(sorted(data, key=_key), key=_key):
    result.append(next(g))

print(result)
# [(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 2), (3, 0, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: I like this but it misses the length requirement.

Comment: @mVChr I missed that. Fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of your problem comes mainly from the fact that you have two independent filters you want to implement. A good way to go about filtering on data with this sort of requirement is to use `groupby`. However, before you can do that you need to sort first. Since you normally sort over one key, you'll need to sort twice before you can group:

```
from itertools import groupby

def lensumFilter(data):
    return [next(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(sorted(data, key = len), key = sum), 
        key = lambda x: (len(x), sum(x)))]

>>> print(lensumFilter( [(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1), (0, 0, 1)] )
[(0, 0, 1), (0, 2, 1)]

>>> print(lensumFilter( [(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1), (0, 0, 0, 3), (0, 0, 1)] )
[(0, 0, 1), (0, 2, 1), (0, 0, 0, 3)]

>>> print(lensumFilter( [(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 2), (0, 4), (0, 0, 0, 5), (0, 0, 3)] )
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 4), (0, 2, 2), (0, 0, 0, 5)]
```

Note that if you change how the sorts work, you change how the output will look. For instance, I sorted on length and then sum so my results are in order with respect to sum (smallest sum first) and then in order with respect to length (fewest number of elements first) within sum-groupings. That's why `(0, 1, 2)` comes before `(0, 4)` but `(0, 4)` comes before `(0, 2, 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something concise and more pythonic, you could use the function [filter](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter).
It will keep all the elements that are matching your requirements (here sum being not equal when same length):

```
tup_remove = (0,2,1)
list(filter(lambda current_tup: not (sum(tup_remove) == sum(current_tup) and len(tup_remove) == len(current_tup))
```

For better readability and extensibility, I would encourage you to use a function:

```
def not_same_sum_len_tuple(tup_to_check, current_tuple):
    """Return True when not same sum AND same length"""
    same_sum = sum(tup_to_check) == sum(current_tuple) # Check the sum
    same_len = len(tup_remove) == len(current_tuple) # Check the length
    return not (same_sum and same_len)

tup_remove = (0,2,1)
list(filter(lambda current_tup: not_same_sum_len_tuple(tup_remove, current_tup), tup_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler solution but may not be performant. Just make a `dict` with `(len(t), sum(t))` as keys and the `tuple`s as values. The last `tuple` stays.

```
lst = [(0,1,2), (0,2,1), (0,0,1)]
d = {(len(t), sum(t)): t for t in lst}
list(d.values())
```

In one line;

```
list({(len(t), sum(t)): t for t in lst}.values())
```

To make it performant just memoize `len` and `sum`.

```
from functools import lru_cache
mlen, msum = (lru_cache(maxsize=None)(f) for f in (len, sum))
list({(mlen(t), msum(t)): t for t in lst}.values())
```